# MVC Repository Pattern - disposing multiple repositories?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository, repository-pattern

In my application I'm trying to apply Repository Pattern using [this ASP.NET guide](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application), but without using Generic Repository and Unit of Work.

The thing that concerns me is disposing. At the moment, my application disposes the `DbContext` by using the standard `Dispose()` controller method:

```
LibraryContext db = new LibraryContext();
//
...
//
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

But how to dispose multiple repositories? For example, I've got three of them: `bookRepository`, `userRepository` and `collectionRepository`. Should I then dispose them all in the method, like:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        bookRepository.Dispose();
        userRepository.Dispose();
        collectionRepository.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Is this a correct approach?
Thank you for answers.

Comment: No, I am not using Unity.

Answer (score 1):

You can create base repository which is extended by the others. In the ctor of base repository you can initialize DbContext class and when you want to dispose you can call base.Dispose. It should be something like this:

```
public class BaseRepository<T> where T : BaseEntityWithId, new()
{
    //Represent the context of the database.
    public DbContext myContext { get; set; }

    //Represent a virtual table of the database.
    protected IDbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }

    //Represents base constructor of the base repository.
    public BaseRepository()
    {
        this.myContext = new Context();
        this.DbSet = this.Context.Set<T>();
    }

    public IObjectContextAdapter GetObjectContextAdapter()
    {
        return (IObjectContextAdapter)this.Context;
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.Context != null)
        {
            this.Context.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

If you really don't want to create base repository even for one Dispose() method you should dispose them 1 by 1.

Comment: he still have the same problem, he have to call dispose.base three times!

Comment: Yes, but he asks "is this a correct approach" and my answer is no, it's not. It will work but he skip important patterns and best practices.